# Why does Firefox DevTools' Debugger show 'loadSourceError'?

Tags: javascript, apache2, firefox-developer-tools

Consider this simple HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('1');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I enable Firefox JavaScript Debugger (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), the panel shows me the following error message instead of the source code:

> Error loading from source:
>   loadSourceError

What am I doing wrong?

My bet is that it comes from some server setting, since it works fine from another server (as well as locally), but I cannot identify any noticeable difference between both configurations (apache.conf are identical, /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ configuration is similar, enabled modules are the same. I had the hope that installing the javascript-common debian package would help, but it does not…).

JavaScript itself is served correctly, though (even the embedded JS), and there is no loading problem for JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

It seems that [the debugger has issues with internationalized domain names (IDN)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1192763).